# How to safely open/close files in python 2.4

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.4

I'm currently writing a small script for use on one of our servers using Python.   The server only has Python 2.4.4 installed.

I didn't start using Python until 2.5 was out, so I'm used to the form:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    # do stuff with f
```

However, there is no `with` statement before 2.5, and I'm having trouble finding examples about the proper way to clean up a file object manually.

What's the best practice for disposing of file objects safely when using old versions of python?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

See [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> When you’re done with a file, call f.close() to close it and free up any system resources taken up by the open file. After calling f.close(), attempts to use the file object will automatically fail.

Hence use `close()` elegantly with `try/finally`:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')

try:
    # do stuff with f
finally:
    f.close()
```

This ensures that even if `# do stuff with f` raises an exception, `f` will still be closed properly.

Note that `open` should appear *outside* of the `try`. If `open` itself raises an exception, the file wasn't opened and does not need to be closed. Also, if `open` raises an exception its result is *not* assigned to `f` and it is an error to call `f.close()`.

Comment: Very simple, thanks.   For some reason I was expecting that I'd need something more involved.

Comment: If `open` fails, an exception will be raised before the `try/finally` block is even entered.  So `close` will not be called. (That's why you should call `open` before the `try`.)

Comment: @TM I added a note about `open` raising an exception.

Comment: This is what the with statement translates to behind the scenes.

Comment: @Jon-Eric what if program was shut down when executing try blocks, would `f` be closed properly?

Comment: @stanleyerror Yes `f` will be closed properly as long the shut down triggers a Python exception. (E.g., Ctrl-C)

Comment: @Jon-Eric I add a print next to the close function in finally block. However, I pressed Ctrl-C when executing try block, nothing is printed. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @stanleyerror I'd suggest asking that as a separate question where you can post the test code you're using and solicit answers from others. (I don't know the details of exactly how Python shuts down on various platforms.)

Comment: Opening the file should happen within the try.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge If you do that, and close the file in the `finally` block, when an exception occurs while trying to open the file, the code in the `finally` block will still be executed. This means that another exception occurs since you try to close a file that was never opened, and may try to use a reference that hasn't been created.

Comment: @RikSchoonbeek I have not been doing Python for a little while now, but my assumption at second glance here is that the `try` statement will not be reached if an exception is thrown by `open`. Context is key.

Comment: @RikSchoonbeek See my response below for the most robust solution, along the lines of AnthonyRutledge but without the issue you refer above.

Answer (score 33):

In the above solution, repeated here:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')

try:
    # do stuff with f
finally:
   f.close()
```

if something bad happens (you never know ...) after opening the file successfully and before the try, the file will not be closed, so a safer solution is:

```
f = None
try:
    f = open('file.txt', 'r')

    # do stuff with f

finally:
    if f is not None:
       f.close()
```

Comment: Using a with open(...) statement, no matter how the with block is finished (even with an exception) file is closed

Comment: @darkgaze `with open(...)` is definitely the best choice in modern Python.

Answer (score 13):

No need to close the file according to the docs if you use with:

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks:

```
>>> with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

More here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score -5):

Here is example given which so how to use `open` and "python `close`

```
from sys import argv
script,filename=argv
txt=open(filename)
print "filename %r" %(filename)
print txt.read()
txt.close()
print "Change the file name"
file_again=raw_input('>')
print "New file name %r" %(file_again)
txt_again=open(file_again)
print txt_again.read()
txt_again.close()
```

It's necessary to how many times you opened file have to close that times.

Comment: If an exception is raised after `open` but before `close`, the file won't be properly closed using this approach. Using `with` or `try`/`finally` closes the file properly even in the presence of exceptions.