# How to save the output of os.system to .csv file?

Tags: python, csv, save

before writing this post, I tried to do it by myself but give up.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129107/python-how-to-save-the-output-of-os-system) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output) but I could not get it

This is the code to show us latency data:

```
import os
x = os.system("ping 192.168.1.1")
```

The output is:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.47 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.97 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.02 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.74 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=2.74 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=2.08 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.087/2.674/3.020/0.319 ms
```

I would like to only save these data like this figure
[image]

Comment: hmm, how did you get the second row? looks like it's for pinging the same server

Comment: I only ran it twice, you can skip it.

Comment: If you want to redirect the output of a command to a file I suggest you use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. You will still need to reformat into into CSV format.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have already started using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.popen()` rather than the `os.system()` function to return the output to a variable.

`os.popen()` executes the task in background and return the output, while `os.system()` execute the task in a terminal.

Here is the full code to extract the ip statistics to a .csv file (Linux only) :

```
import os

ip = "192.168.1.1"

x = os.popen("ping -c 4 "+ip).read()

print (x)

x = x.splitlines()

x = x[len(x)-1]


x = x.replace("rtt min/avg/max/mdev = ","")

x = x.replace(" ms" , "")
x = x.replace("/" , ",")

x = ip +","+ x

file = open("newfile.csv","w")
file.write("PING,min,avg,max,mdev\n")
file.write(x)
file.close()
print(x)
print(".csv created successfully")
```

**Note** : The `x = os.popen("ping -c 4 "+ip).read()` command represents that the number of times the ping will occur and end is 4(written after `ping -c` ). The number can replaced by any other number, as needed. But this doesn't cause much changes to the result.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work for me.

Comment: What output you are getting ?

Comment: It is nothing FOR first print (x).

Comment: The first code was specifically for windows , but I think you are in Linux , So I have written the code for Linux now. See above.