# Close file in finally block doesn't work

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
    fnf.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    fr.close();
}
```

The `fr.close()` shows an error:

> fr cannot be resolved

I had read that closing a file in the finally block is a good practice.
What is that am doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The variable `fr` only has scope within the `try` block. It is out of scope in the finally block. You need to declare it *before* the `try` block:

```
FileReader fr = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fr != null) {
        try {
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // This is unrecoverable. Just report it and move on
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is quite a common pattern of code, so it's good to remember it for future similar situations.

Consider throwing `IOException` from this method - printing track traces isn't very helpful to callers, *and* you wouldn't need the nested try catch around `fr.close()`

Comment: If I do that then it says I need to add another Try block while closing the file. I read a previous post where it was said that nothing can be done about that. So, this would be the best way is it?

Comment: Yes, that is annoying.  One often writes a utility method, named "closeQuietly" (or similar) to do this.  It catches and ignores the Exception.

Comment: See edited answer for nested `try/catch` - also a common pattern

Comment: Is there a reason not to do the `FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);` outside?  This would eliminate the need to check `fr != null`, no?  A complication is that `catch (FileNotFoundException e)` has to be moved to an outer try: https://gist.github.com/cben/6e092536e8f2072ab83f but that still reads cleaner to me.  But maybe that's just my [Python habits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3770375/239657).

Answer (score 10):

Now finally block is not needed,

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);){

    String line = null;

    }

} catch(FileNotFoundException fnf) {
    fnf.printStackTrace();
}
```

now automatically close your readers

Comment: Yes, but only in Java 7.  Java 6 and earlier do not have this.

Comment: In case anyone wonders why is this, search for "try with resources"

Comment: more info: [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your scopes. If you really want to use that syntax you should fix it like this:

```
FileReader fr = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
    fnf.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if( fr != null)
       fr.close();
}
```

that way, fr will exist in the finally's block scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FileReader file1 = null;
        try{
            file1 = new FileReader("blaaa.txt");//this file does not exist
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
        catch (IOException e)  {e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            try{file1.close();}
            catch (NullPointerException e){
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("Thank you, please try again");
            }
        }
    }
```