# MonoDroid: Path to Assets to unzip a file with .NET framework

Tags: c#, android, mono, zip, xamarin.android

I am using the `SharpZip .NET Zip Library` to unzip a file found in the `Assets/MyZipFolder` folder.

I need to get the full path so that I can use the following:

```
ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(_zipFile))
```

How do I get the path to `Assets/MyZipFolder/MyZip.zip` to pass to a .NET File.OpenRead command?

Comment: Assets don't have a physical representation in the filesystem so there is no path. But it should work like in standard Android too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Context you can simply open a read stream using:

```
 using (var stream = Context.Assets.Open("MyZipFolder/MyZip.zip"))
 { 
      var s = new ZipInputStream(stream);
      // do read here ...
 }
```

Be careful that the file is marked as an `AndroidAsset` for build action, the absolute path is: "file:///android_asset" and remember that file names in android are case sensitive.