# Finding file in webview android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access a file in a web view. The file name is "UserRules.txt" and it is saved wherever android saves its default files.

My web files are in the "assets" folder.

Any idea of the filepath I should use?

Comment: This should answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: What are "default files"?