# Android Assets Manager Exception

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.android

I wanted to use Android Assets and followed the [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_android_assets) in the official docs.

Have set the asset type to `AndroidAssets` like it says, but it was throwing exceptions for not finding the file. I have a rooted device so upon inspection I noticed that the files are not actually on the device at all (/data/data/com.company.application/files/SomeFile.txt).

**EDIT:**

```
String filename = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "AboutAssets.txt");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: Did you perform a full rebuild of your application after adding the asset? The fact that your device is rooted should not matter.

Comment: Did you set the file's `BuildAction` to `AndroidAsset`?

Comment: I did both of these things, yes.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted this a while ago and ended up not using Xamarin because I never found a solution. I have recently come back to Xamarin and the latest updates seem to have fixed this issue - the same project now works fine with no changes made.

So if anyone else encounters this - try updating.

Answer (score 0):

Android Assets are stored in the APK file, so you can't find the file using your code. There is no absolute path to those files.

Just use [`Assets.Open`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Res.AssetManager.Open/p/System.String/) to access assets, exactly like what taught in the [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_android_assets#Reading_Assets).

Comment: Crashes in the same way unfortunately :( Then I read on the forums to try the Path.Combine approach.

Comment: How come? `File not found` exception? Use the exact same line of ` using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")) content = sr.ReadToEnd ();` in the tutorial. It can hardly get exceptions.

Comment: File not found or part of file path not found. Definitely set to AndroidAsset though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = assets.open(filename);
```

The context Object refer to the Context of Application.

Comment: I added Context object. Try again.

Comment: This thread can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets