# Android Java - reading dictionary assets

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This might be a duplicated thread however after trying out several and multiple threads my problem still continues :/

I have this method which reads a dictionary and does decryption with it . However, I have no idea how to get it to read the dictionary. I drag and dropped my dictionary to the assets folder and then used this code.

```
try {
    System.out.println("Dictionary Initialize");
    BufferedReader inputReader;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/assets/dictionary-english.txt");
    BufferedReader dictionary = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String checktext;

    while ((checktext = dictionary.readLine()) != null) {
        dictionaryset.add(checktext);
    }
    System.out.println("Dictionary Successfully Initialized");

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error! reading!");
}
```

After several test, I have confirmed that it could not even reach the while loop as the try and catch catches the error. It also caught an `IOException` error. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

This is my error from the `logcat`

```
10-06 14:54:50.555: W/System.err(1980): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/dictionary-english.txt (No such file or directory)
10-06 14:54:50.555: W/System.err(1980):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
10-06 14:54:50.555: W/System.err(1980):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
10-06 14:54:50.555: W/System.err(1980):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
10-06 14:54:50.565: W/System.err(1980):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:132)
```

Edited: Tried using

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
```

However I get an error on the `getAssets()` which is **"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAssets() from the type ContextWrapper"**

========================================================================

Answer:

```
BufferedReader dictionary = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("dictionary-english")));
```

I used this line of code to get my file and in the method I removed the `static` which solved my cannot make a static reference problem

```
eg;   private static String run1(String cipherText){  --> private String run1(String cipherText){
```

Comment: Did you try printing the exception stack trace using `ex.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Error posted! thanks for reminding me about log cat

Comment: Rather than use a full pathname, use AssetManager to access the file.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: I just used the assetmanager to make one of this
      AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
however i get an error on the getAssets
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAssets() from the type ContextWrapper

Comment: Ok i found my solution . :/ however i lack the reputation to actually post my answer .....

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your solution?