# OpenCV file operation in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I have build and Run c++ lib  [asm lib](http://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv/)   and now i need to port it on Android.
There are some file operation are there so i need to get some files from Andorid assets.I have try to load on native side using
 file:///android_asset and other method also but still having error

Model file not found file:///android_asset/muct76.model

If anyone know how to load file in OpenCV for Android then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This two links were very useful for me when I tried to import libs for OpenCV in Android:

1. [OpenCV documentation about native part in Android](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#cdt-builder)
2. [NDK App for Android](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/) -> This one saved me, since I had a lot of doubts after reading the first (OpenCV documentation). You can go directly to the Step 4.

And here you can see how to read files from assets:
[read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

I hope they help you too

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i need to work on native(c++) using jni