# Own data files in Android

Tags: android, file, android-resources

I make some small app that should load some `data.xml` file. I would like to put this in `data\data.xml`.
But where should i put it in my Android prject (i use Eclipse)?
When i try to make directory `data` under `assets` or `res`, compiler complains this is invalid directory name.
And then how to call this directory path (i run it under emulator which has own environment)?

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed to create your own folder inside the `res` folder. this folder is reserved for Layouts and other Android specific resources (xml-defined Arrays, Strings, etc.).

But creating a folder inside the `assets` folder is working fine in my project and should be the default way to ship files with your bundled App.

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9544781/1515052) to see how to access files within the `assets` folder from your Activity.
You need to call [`Activity.getAssets()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getAssets%28%29)

Comment: I had to clean project and compiler stop complains about data directory. And what if i would like to have an access from standard class? Should i pass activity to it or there is some other way (more Java-like)?

Comment: If it is sure that your Class accesses the assets, after the Activity is started you could hand over a (static) link to the context like in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/1515052

Comment: I will precise my question, is it possible to get file like this:
File file = new File("some path");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));