# Failed access assets folder

Tags: android, android-assets

In android, I've used a font from my assets folder and worked correctly. Suddenly today i can't access to this font in my assets folder and the terminal generates

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
```

this is the piece of code

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("App");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Redressed.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: how did you get this font from assets folder ??

Comment: This is duplication of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Answer (score 0):

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "abc.ttf");