# Android studio assets folder

Tags: android, assets

when i try to create a webView in android studio and point it here: file:///src/main/assets/www/index.html, it keeps saying that it can not find the file path.

Thanks in advance.

Mitch

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Answer (score 0):

Use `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`. There is no `src/main/assets/` directory on the device -- that is simply how your project is structured. Assets are packaged as part of the ZIP archive that is the APK file; `file:///android_asset/` is a means for `WebView` to pull from the project assets.

Comment: so, do i create a folder called assets under app?

Comment: @mitchellanderson: No, you keep them right where they are. The problem is in your Java code, not where the files reside.

Comment: @mitchellanderson: Then I don't know what to tell you. If you have `app/src/main/assets/www/index.html`, and you use `loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")`, it should work.

Comment: Maybe post your code @mitchellanderson. Are you in an Activity or a Fragment or some other class? There are a number of things which could affect your outcome.

Comment: @mitchellanderson: That seems fine. Depending on what is in the HTML, you might need the `INTERNET` permission (e.g., if it is trying to load CSS off of a Web site). What specifically are your symptoms?

Comment: i just have a <p> tag and am linking to javascript and CSS files that are in the same directory as teh index.htlml