# Reading lines randomly from a file

Tags: android, eclipse, file

I try to read lines randomly from a txt file and show this line in a toast later,

I put the file in assets folder and wrote this code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("assets/tips.txt"));
String line = reader.readLine();
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while (line != null) {
 lines.add(line);
 line = reader.readLine();
}
Random r = new Random();
String randomLine = lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, randomLine, 30000);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
```

whats the mistake I did so my app don't show any thing and crash?

Comment: Show us your logcat.

Comment: 05-10 18:41:11.735: W/System.err(12818): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/tips.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: this is first row only

Comment: probably see this question for how to read asset file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets