# Custom Folder in Android Project

Tags: android, directory

I need to put a folder in my Android project that I can access using `File myDir = new File(path-to-dir);` but I can't seem to find a way to do this. I have tried putting it in the `assets` folder but I need to access my folder itself, so I can perform operations on it once I have it in a `File` object. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to copy the directory and its contents from `assets/` to the local filesystem. Assets are not files on the device.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Create a folder ins assets folder and place your files there..

**Step 2 :** assuming you have a folder named myfolder in assets folder, try this code

```
ReadFromfile("/myfolder/myfile.txt", mContext);
```

and the function is

```
public String ReadFromfile(String fileName, Context context) {
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream fIn = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
        fIn = context.getResources().getAssets()
                .open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        input = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            returnString.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (isr != null)
                isr.close();
            if (fIn != null)
                fIn.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return returnString.toString();
}
```

Credits to [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)