# Reading .txt file from Asset Folder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, assets

I am reading .txt files from `Asset` Folder by Passing a String which is in the previous activity list item.

Let us consider,`Recyclerview` item size in 5.

1. Android          -- Item 1
2. IOS              -- Item 2
3. BlackBerry       -- Item 3
4. Symbian          -- Item 4
5. Bada             -- Item 5

When I click Android,the "Android" String is passed through an Intent and 
Assigned to the variable of ***Song***.

```
 InputStream inputstream = getResources().getAssets().open(***Song*** + ".txt");
```

and reads the Android.txt file from the Asset Folder. Only the first item is called. When I click other items in the list, `intent` String passed to next activity, but did not open the respective .txt file from folder. It jumped to catch.

Here is my code.

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
        Song = i.getExtras().getString("Title");
        textView.setText(Song);
        System.out.println(".....1");
        try {
            System.out.println(".....2");
            InputStream inputstream = getResources().getAssets().open(Song + ".txt");
            System.out.println(".....3");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            String m = reader.toString();
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(".....4");
            m = total.toString();
            System.out.println(".....5" + m);

            textView.setText(m);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            System.out.println(".....6");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(".....7" + ex);
        }
```

System.out.println     ---> Prints all in the 1st item click

Except clicking of 1st item, print only the following in LogCat.
System.out: .....1
System.out: .....2

Adapter Class at where I click the `RecyclerView` item,

```
public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context con;

    ArrayList<String> songHeading = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences pref;
    String MyPREFERENCES = "Preference";


    public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> heading) {
        this.con = context;
        this.songHeading = heading;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.song_list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        pref = con.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        holder.txtSong.setText(songHeading.get(position));

        holder.Clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Title", songHeading.get(position));
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songHeading.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public TextView txtSong;
        LinearLayout Clicker;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            txtSong = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Clicker = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Clicker);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

After changing code like the following getting Error in Verbose

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_list_item2);
        context = this;

        pref = this.context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Song = i.getExtras().getString("Title");
        textView.setText(Song);
        System.out.println(".....1");
        textView.setText(loadJSONFromAsset());
    }

    private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open(Song + ".txt");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

at hitesh.androidjsonapp.MainActivity.loadJSONFromAsset(MainActivity.java:40) pointed this line

```
   InputStream is = getAssets().open(Song + ".txt");
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a string array resource?

Comment: I have to read more than 1000 files from Assert Folder.

Comment: You didn't mention that.

Comment: Post your item click code. where you create an intent and send title value

Comment: If I can read the 5 files, it is an easy to read even it more than 10000. So for easy proceeding of question I mentioned 5 files.

Comment: So little as 5 files are well suitable for arrays.

Comment: Please check my adapter code

Comment: @ParamaSudha I think your problem with your onBindViewHolder(...) method. Just make sure with Log, the  " Song = i.getExtras().getString("Title");" giving the respective item you click in the listview

Comment: Yeah.Even I checked. In Log.e prints when  it jumped to catch.

Comment: I guess the issue is in  InputStream inputstream = getResources().getAssets().open(Song + ".txt");

Comment: Except 1st item  clicking

Comment: Make sure the following line print the respective title System.out.println(".....1"+Song) and add finally block with your try..catch  there you need to close the inputstream

Comment: Okay...Let me do and intimate you once I analyze it

Comment: Printed Like the following

Comment: 13588-13588/hitesh.androidjsonapp I/System.out: .....1   \n
                                                                   BlackBerry

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file name is not append with any special characters(\n) or empty space and add finally block with your try..catch there you need to close the inputstream

```
13588-13588/hitesh.androidjsonapp I/System.out: .....1 \n BlackBerry
```

Comment: Actually \n is edited by me. I got the Lo.g result as 13588-13588/hitesh.androidjsonapp I/System.out: .....1  ---> 1st line BlackBerry ---> in second line. By showing separate texts to you it I used \n

Comment: Okay...I will check by using inputstream.close()

Comment: :P  please check and let me know..Make sure the file name is exactly same as you have in asset folder

Comment: Did not find any changes in Result.Still it is the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9544781/1537419 can you please check this answer, may be character encoding creating problem for you..

Comment: I am Sorry...Even I referred & used the above link code.But have not seen any changes in my result.

Comment: Please check my UPDATION... Error in Verbose

Comment: Please help me to fix it @Srinivasan

Comment: Can you just rename the first file(which is working fine) and save it as BlackBerry.txt in your asset folder. If its working fine the problem is not on your code.

Comment: Noticed that only 0th item click file is reading from asset. It may  be Android,BlackBerry and anything. (I rearranged item as BlackBerry,Android.....) .Now BlackBerry.txt is opened.

Comment: Then I am sure the problem is not with files, Its because of how we are starting the Intent

Comment: Instead of calling intent from adapter, why dont you pass the selected item from Adapter to Activity with the help of Interface

Comment: Okay...Let me try.

Comment: And even I used SharedPreference , but it was worked the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110891/discussion-between-parama-sudha-and-srinivasan).