# Security on android volley POST Request at php file

Tags: php, android, security, android-volley

I have an app dealing with money transactions so it's very important to have security. I use passwords and some other tricks when the user sends requests to my php file, but I want to know if it is possible to somehow let the php file verify that the POST method sends Only from my app and Volley?

I don't want to accept requests from web pages or anything else; only my request With Android Volley Proceeded.

P.S : Send a Values from POST method and check on PHP to identify is Not a Safe Method, and easily can hacked.

Comment: Can you re-write your question and try making it clearer, you want to make sure the data is coming from your app?

Comment: @Mehdi yes bro thats exactly my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending your request from android, encrypt your payload using some encryption, probably RSA, and then decrypt that request on your server side, if decrypted successfully, you can be sure that the request is genuine and is not altered.

Generate a private key file in PHP

```
$config = array(
   "digest_alg" => "sha512",
   "private_key_bits" => 4096,
   "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);
$keys = openssl_pkey_new($config);
$priv = openssl_pkey_get_private($keys);
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($priv, 'private.pem');
```

Generate a public .der-file from the private key file with OpenSSL

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public.der
```

Import and use the public key in Java (Android side):

```
File pubKeyFile = new File("public.der");
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pubKeyFile));
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) pubKeyFile.length()];

dis.readFully(keyBytes);
dis.close();

X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

Encode your payload in Android (get bytes according to your requirement)

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
String payload = "tejashwi kalp taru";
byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes()));
String encryptedData = new String(encryptedBytes));
//send encryptedData to server for decryption
```

Decrypt your payload in PHP:

```
$fp = fopen("private.pem", "r");
$privateKey = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);

$res = openssl_get_privatekey($privateKey);
$cipher = base64_decode($cipher);
openssl_private_decrypt( $cipher, $decrypted, $res, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING );

// $decrypted is the result
```

Git repo for demo: https://github.com/tejashwikalptaru/encrypted-communication

Comment: you didnt use encrypted text in last part in php , where i should put encrypted text to get decrypted?

Comment: `$cipher` is your encrypted text which you sent from your android device

Comment: @ali22 I have added a git repo, check that out

Comment: where i should put public.der file in my package?

Comment: put it in your assets folder, and read it from there. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38121187/2520628

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. Can't be done. Whatever your app does, someone can do the exact same thing without using your app.

You can make it hard to replicate what your app does, though. Using encryption, as already suggested, accomplishes this: attacker would have to extract the key from your app and replicate your encryption logic.

In similar vein, you can set custom headers, you can check other headers match what your app would send, you can check details of the payload to see if they match what the app would send, and so on. Any of these make it harder to construct a request that would pass as legitimate, but none would prevent it.

Some attack vectors can be prevented, though: for example, if you specifically want to prevent requests from unmodified web browsers, you can check headers that can't be set from Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name