# Where shall I put an existing DB in a android project

Tags: android

Im making an app, and want to port it to android which im new to. Where should i place the db? and is the code below enough to successfully connect and query the db or do i need more to just test if it works?

```
 String path = "WHERE_SHOULD_I_PLACE_MY_DB_?";

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,     
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from table", null);

            String something = cursor.getString(1);

            System.out.println(something);
```

Comment: Do you have an existing SQLITE DB file or are you trying to create a database from scratch?

Comment: I have one and want query it for testing

Comment: this would help, https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 0):

I've never done something similar, but if I understood your question that you have a db, I would recommend you to put it in the assets folder of your android project and then move it to the internal sd card of the application. There is usually a /app_internal_sd_card/databases/some_db.db where they are stored, but since you're not creating it yourself you can't put it there straight away.

Potentially you can read directly from the assets, but I would cal that a bad practice. :)

Some info on reading from assets: [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)
or
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)

Comment: Okay so tried to just create the tables from scratch, and this is so messy compared to sqlite in plain java. I will get back to this later when i figure out how i can even insert  something and query it back. this was so painfree in java :P

Comment: But if you create the tables from scratch you don't need to move it around then just follow a tutorial on setting one up. :) My reply was only if you were to reuse your old db.

For example here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: So i started from scratch and set up a single table for testing purposes. Now I messed up and i get wrong info when querying. How can i even tell how many records are stored in the table when all I get is a number as a result? How can I enter the db that has been created upon launching the app? Do I have to access it from within the emulator or is it possible in IntelliJ which Im using?

Answer (score 0):

Android have API for SQL lite, just use it ant it will put db to correct place:

> Just like files that you save on the device's internal storage,
>   Android stores your database in private disk space that's associated
>   application. Your data is secure, because by default this area is not
>   accessible to other applications.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html