# How to store initial data in android apk file?

Tags: android

I'm writing an android weather app, which needs a city information list.

The list is quite long, and spends long time to be downloaded from internet.

So I want to save it in my .apk file, and load it without internet connection, but don't know how.

I tried to save it in a java class, but it's toooo huge and costs much memory.

Are there some ways to solve it? Thx!

Comment: for iOS create new question with 'ios' tag, please

Comment: sorry for that, thought the subject is mainly android and not appropriate to be shown in ios timeline. It's removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you look at res/assets?

I assume that you probably have some sort of json/xml data that you want to pre-package with your app if so, then load the json/xml into the res/assets and it'll just be a file included with your apk.

### Ref

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: Yes it's a JSON string. Just drag it in res/assets? And how to read it, maybe just like reading a file?

Comment: Yep, just like that. Refer here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html also some more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: Didn't forget, but the network between sf and China is too slow......even hard to refresh

Answer (score 2):

You can store it in **SQLite database** or use **plain text** then save it in raw or asset resource in your app project.

For SQLite, try [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) which will help you with storing data from a predefined database.

Here an excerpt from its README:

> An Android helper class to manage database creation and version
>   management using an application's raw asset files.
>
> This class provides developers with a simple way to ship their Android
>   app with an existing SQLite database (which may be pre-populated with
>   data) and to manage its initial creation and any upgrades required
>   with subsequent version releases.
>
> It is implemented as an extension to SQLiteOpenHelper, providing an
>   efficient way for ContentProvider implementations to defer opening and
>   upgrading the database until first use.
>
> Rather than implementing the onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods to
>   execute a bunch of SQL statements, developers simply include
>   appropriately named file assets in their project's assets directory.
>   These will include the initial SQLite database file for creation and
>   optionally any SQL upgrade scripts.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `arrays` from xml resources. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="cities">
        <item>New York</item>
        <item>London</item>
        <item>Moscow</item>
        ....
    </string-array>
</resources>
```