# How to get a refference to a txt file and get a string from it

Tags: java, android

I have some programming experience, but I have no experience in working with text files in android. I am using android studio, and making an app which gets a `String` from a file, and than displays it.

I did my research, and  according to android.developer.com I need to use `FileReader`, but I still have some questions:

1.In which folder do I put the .txt files in?

2.How do I make a `FileReader` reference to the `.txt` file?

I have searched this site and other sites, and there are a lot of questions like mine, but none answer the questions I have..

EDIT:
Can someone please give me the whole code/ step by step instructions on how to do this. From where to place the file, to how to access and make a string out of it

Comment: Did you at least read this in your search: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#InternalVsExternalStorage

Comment: @MorrisonChang that tells me how to make a file, but doesn't tell me where to put it and how to access it

Comment: i have implemented this using .xls file do you want the code snippet?, you can import .xls file and get the data from it

Comment: @Darpan S. Raut yes please, that would be great

Comment: ok ill do it wait

Answer (score 0):

**In which folder do I put the text files in?**

Well, it is really up to you. You can even create one and customise your file tree. Note that root directories may vary in different devices so it is highly recommended that you should reference from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

For example,

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"yourCustomFolder");
if(!dir.exists())
        fileDir.mkdirs();
```

by that, you can see on your phone that the folder has been created.

For further information, like creating files to your custom folder, you can reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422059/2006009) answer.

Comment: You can also put your text file in asset folder and then read data from it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets 
or
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/android-read-file-from-assets.html

Comment: I made an texts folder, so would I do `File file = new File(Enviorment.getExternalStorageDirecory() + "texts\file_name.txt");

Comment: That would do. Please refer to the link to set string on your file

Comment: Does this seem right `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "assets/1.txt");
        FileReader read = new FileReader(file);
        String str = read.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

**compile** :

```
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.0.1-FINAL'
```

Below is the code to read file from **.xls** file.
-this code snippets is for reading **only one** field customername, you can **add more cells** to it.

```
 /**
 * Method to Import XLS file to Database
 *
 * @param uriFile
 */
private void importCsvFileToDatabase(Uri uriFile) {
    try {
        InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriFile);
        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        boolean isFirstRow = true;
        int i = 1;

        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow rowhead = mySheet.getRow((short) i++);
            if (rowhead == null) {
                break;
            }
            String customerName = "";

            CustomerInfo customerInfodb = new CustomerInfo();
            try {
                customerName = rowhead.getCell((short) 0).toString();
                customerInfodb.setCustomerName(customerName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                customerInfodb.setCustomerName("");
                Log.e("TAG", "err" + e.getMessage());
            }

                CustomerInfo.saveCustomerInfo(context, customerInfodb);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("LOG", "err" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```