# How to properly access a text file in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, android-studio

When I try to read some files in my Android app they appear to not exist, here is my code:

```
public class ReadFiles1 {

    //Static Scanner and File Objects
    static Scanner s;
    

    // Static method that returns an ArrayList
    static ArrayList<String> words (String filename){

        //Instantiate File with file name within parameters
        File n = new File(filename);

        //Instantiate Scanner s with f variable within parameters
        //surround with try and catch to see whether the file was read or not
        try {
            s = new Scanner(n);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Problem here");
        }

        //Instantiate a new ArrayList of String type
        ArrayList<String> theWord = new ArrayList <String>();

        //while it has next ..
        while(s.hasNext()){
            //Initialise str with word read
            String str=s.next();

            //add to ArrayList
            theWord.add(str);

        }
        //return ArrayList
        return theWord;

    }
```

I don't know what the problem is, I put the txt files in the same package as the .java files.
This is the error I get when runnning this:
check this link for PICTURE(https://ibb.co/cn3QCv)

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/numbers.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: In eclipse it runs fine

Comment: Please check  whether permission in Android Mainfest file , If not add permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: check full path of file, I think thats the only problem..it simply means there is no such file.

Comment: @ELITE I did write the full path, but it didn't work.

Comment: show me the full path and also add how you're calling the `words` method..

Comment: @RohithKrishnan I added the permission, but still get the same error...

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test/lotos/numbers.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I want to know, how you are calling this method...

Comment: @ELITE    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String testing = generate();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(testing);


    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put your text files in java folder instead put it in

`app/src/main/res/raw/` folder and read it in program using below code.

```
static ArrayList<String> words (InputStream in) {
    try {
        s = new Scanner(in);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Problem here");
    }
```

and call this method from any activity or service using below code

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.numbers);
ArrayList<String> words = ReadFiles1.words(in);
```

or if you're calling this method from any other class then should have `context` reference

```
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.numbers);
ArrayList<String> words = ReadFiles1.words(in);
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I got this error message: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/numbers.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I don't understand why the files are not visible, they are in the same package, in Eclipse I didn't have any problem...

Comment: I just want to make clear, the txt files are in the app, not in an external stotrage, I'm just saying because of the suggestion .getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Where you put that txt file..if you can show project structure then I can tell you the cause

Comment: try [read file from project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Comment: I changed the answer...check once

Comment: @ELIOT unfortunately I couldn't do it...What I am trying to do is read a text file, put every word in an arraylist and use it as needed later. This is very easy in Eclipse ,but challenging for me in Android Studio, I don't know why...

Comment: Is there a simple way to import my java code from eclipse into android studio and use the functions that I have written in my eclipse java code for android studio as well?