# Reading Numbers from a textfile

Tags: java, android, arrays, text-files

I want to read and print the numbers from the Textfile (WLTP.txt) in the assets folder as an array, but the output of my code is everytime `null`. I wonder why it is skipping the try part and jumping to the catch part.

```
public class WLTPc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] data = readFiles("WLTP.txt");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }

    public static int [] readFiles(String file) {
        try {

            File f = new File(file);
            Scanner s = new Scanner (f);
            int ctr = 0;
            while (s.hasNextInt()) {
                ctr ++;
                s.nextInt();
            }
            int[] arr = new int[ctr];

            Scanner s1= new Scanner(f);

            for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
                arr[i] = s1.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            return arr;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing file name **directly** and accessing it in `File()` object.

As you are accessing file from asset you **need to use** `getAssets().open(file))`

It will return `InputStream`. Pass that **InputStream** to `Scanner()` and read you file as you want.

```
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WLTPc {

    private Context context;

    public WLTPc(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int[] readAssetFiles(String file) {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(context.getAssets().open(file));
            int ctr = 0;
            while (s.hasNextInt()) {
                ctr++;
                s.nextInt();
            }
            s.close();
            int[] arr = new int[ctr];

            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(context.getAssets().open(file));

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = s1.nextInt();
            }
            s1.close();
            return arr;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. There are 2 Errors. The bufferedReader in the last if cannot be resolved and there is missing a return in the last catch.

Comment: @UğurGüneş Updated code with errors fixed. Checkout and let me know

Comment: @adityakamble49 Wouldn't it be more efficient to use a collection, e.g. `ArrayList`, and then returning `ArrayList.toArray` instead of reading through the whole file twice?

Comment: @UğurGüneş Yeah. It would. As Its upto you how much you want to optimize it as per your requirement. I was just focusing on getting file from assets and putting into `Scanner` so you can perform your operation.

Comment: @UğurGüneş consider upvoting and approving answer if this works for you :)