# Share and receive simple data from a file

Tags: android, android-sharing

[Using this help](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)
I want to recover the text inside a file, I make a long press on the file, I can choose the application to use, so I take the one I realize, the application takes into account my action, but I cannot recover the text from the file.
The variable “sharedText” is null.
here is the code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textHello = findViewById(R.id.hello);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type   = intent.getType();

    Log.d(TAG," action = "+action); // = android.intent.action.SEND
    Log.d(TAG," type =  "+type);    // = text/plain

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {

            String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

            Log.d(TAG, " sharedText =  " + sharedText); // = null

            if (sharedText != null) {

               textHello.setText(sharedText);

            } else {
                sharedText = "it doesn't work for me";
                textHello.setText(sharedText);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

here is the manifeste

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka, surfing a lot here is the solution to my problem and I hope it will help other people, I saw a lot of similar problems here is the link that helped me
[lien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713245/android-open-file-from-phone-memory-using-intent/52713486#52713486)

and here is the code

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textHello = findViewById(R.id.hello);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    Log.d(TAG, " action = " + action); // = android.intent.action.SEND
    Log.d(TAG, " type =  " + type);    // = text/plain

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {




            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

            Log.d(TAG, " uri =  " + uri);

            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String mLine;
                while ((mLine = r.readLine()) != null) {

                    Log.d(TAG, " text =  " + mLine);

                    text.append(mLine);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            textHello.setText(text);




        }
     }
}
```