# FileNotFoundException in the onCreate() method

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, jsonreader

I keep receiving the `FileNotFoundException` error when trying to load my file into a `JSONReader` using an `InputStream` within my `onCreate` method.

I've tested this code in a simple Java program and it seems to work fine and also reads the JSON file too. However, within Android Studio I keep receiving the `FileNotFoundException`.

Am I referencing the location of the file incorrectly?

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    List<String> linksList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JsonReader reader = null;
        reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("/assets/test.json"));
        reader.beginArray();

        while (reader.hasNext()) {

            String value = reader.nextString();
            linksList.add(value);
        }

        reader.endArray();
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

        fnfe.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the **Log** -

```
12-27 11:56:11.342 20703-20703/com.adam.jsonreader W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/test.json (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:99)
12-27 11:56:11.343 20703-20703/com.adam.jsonreader W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at com.adamkhora.jsonreader.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:43)
```

Here is my project structure:

[image: project_structure]

Comment: your path for asset folder is wrong

Comment: On a Linux system like Android the path `"/assets/test.json"` means that the file is located in the assets folder of the file-system-root not the data directory of the app. For correctly loading assets see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Comment: @Robert Would what you sent still work for a JSONReader using FileReader?

Comment: @Adam just don't use `FileReader`, just use the reader instead as shown in Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `new FileReader("/assets/test.json")`,

use

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("test.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

You need to use the `getAssets()` method to use assets in android.

Comment: Just one minor improvement to your answer: use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `"UTF-8". This saves you one unnecessary catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below snippet by giving file name

```
 try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("test.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do not use this snippet..
From the Java InputStream documentaion : 

**Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.**