# How to access lottie files outside res folder programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know this is a duplicate question or not, but i tried to search similar question according to this.

I want to access the file that located outside **/res** folder programatically.
I already know if we want to access /res folder, then we just call it's id like `getString()`, `getDrawable()` etc.

But in my case, I want to access **anim_empty.json** programatically. How to do that?

[image: Sample image]

Comment: You can use `getAssets().open()` method from `Context` class which will provide you `InputStream` object. I.e. `context.getAssets().open("file name");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the truth, i just wanted to call the Lottie animation files, i thought that i need to write script like the answer above but all i need is just these ([Getting Started With Animations in Android Using Lottie — Kotlin](https://medium.com/@eijaz/animations-in-android-using-lottie-kotlin-679364ed3f26) and [enter link description here](https://expertise.jetruby.com/adding-cool-vector-animations-to-android-apps-with-lottie-273351ee2583)):

```
    lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.empty_hstanim);
    lottieAnimationView.setAnimation("anim_empty.json");
    lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
```

Thanks for the kind answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try following method for accessing JSON data:

```
public static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context mContext, String fileName) {
    String json;
    try {
        InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(fileName);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Modify the method according to your usage..