# How to retrieve text from webview

Tags: java, android

I am Having an `HTML` file in the asset folder. The following is the way I am loading to view the HTML content. I am having a text view. Now I want to retrieve the HTML content in the string and display that in a text view using `text.settext()`. Please suggest me how to retrieve the content in a string.

```
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: Only use a webview if you want to display the web page. Instead load your asset directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737

Comment: i want to show it as a webpage but i want to retrieve content in textview. Eg I am trying to show the webview kind of kindle reader.

Comment: I am sorry but your question doe snot make sens to me. An asset is something you have created therefore you can modify the content. If you want the html asset to contain only text modify it accordingly or extract the text and directly load it into the textview. The use of a WebView is totally unnecessary.