# How can I import a lib file? scanner occur FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

I am getting the following error:

[image: logcat output with the error]

`scan = new Scanner(new File("file:///android_lib/"+StationNM+".csv"));`

I have `아현.csv` in the lib folder, but android throws `FileNotFoundException`.

how can I solve this? adfasdfa

my source is

```
mport java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;

public class model {


    public float modelPredict(String StationNM, String UPandDOWN, int day, int hour, int minute)
    {
 Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("file:///android_lib/"+StationNM+".csv"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArrayList<Integer> model_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String[] record;
            record = scan.nextLine().split(",");
            records.add(record);
        }
}

this issue was solved
```

Comment: your `lib` folder is not compiled into your APK, so yes file not found. Perhaps you want to move the file to your `assets` or `raw` folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: cannot resolve method `getAssets`

Comment: scroll down, you need `context.getAssets`

Comment: you mean `ContextInstance.getAssets();`? also Cannot resolve symbol `ContextInstance`

Comment: Please write down code snippet instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

```
scan = new Scanner(new File("file:///android_lib/"+StationNM+".csv"));
```

The `File` constructor takes filesystem paths. What you are passing:

- Is not a filesystem path, as paths do not have schemes like `file://` or `http://` or `content://`
- Refers to a non-existent directory on the filesystem

> I have 아현.csv in the lib folder

Put it in `src/main/assets/` of your module. Pass in an `AssetManager` to your `modelPredict()` method, and use `open()` on `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` that you can pass to the `Scanner` constructor. You get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity` or `Service`.

Comment: @GoBackess: As I wrote, you get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity` or `Service`.

Comment: i try `AssetManager assetManager = getApplication().getAssets();` but `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.app.Application.getAssets()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @GoBackess: `getApplication()` is returning `null`. If you are trying this in a field initializer of your activity, you need to wait on calling methods like `getApplication()` until `onCreate()` or later.

Comment: @GoBackess: A class named `model` is an odd one for an activity. Did you start `model` using `startActivity()`?

Comment: No this is for calculate class

Comment: and Context doesn't have getAssets()

Comment: public float modelPredict(String StationNM, String UPandDOWN, int day, int hour, int minute) {
        AssetManager assetManager = (AssetManager) Context.getAssets();
occur `Non-static method 'getAssets()' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: @GoBackess: "and Context doesn't have getAssets()" -- yes, [it does](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getAssets()). You are trying to call `getAssets()` on the class, not on an object that is an instance of a `Context`, such as your `Activity` or `Fragment`.