# .PEM certificates (SSL) in Android Studio

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, ssl, pem

I need to use the .pem certificates to access the database but I think I am not doing well. Putting .toString () doesn't seem very correct.

I currently have the certificates in the "assets" folder.

Do I have to convert the .PEM certificates to another type of certificates with another extension?

```
        props.setProperty("sslrootcert",mContext.getAssets().open("ca-cert.pem").toString());
        props.setProperty("sslkey",mContext.getAssets().open("client-key.pem").toString());
        props.setProperty("sslcert",mContext.getAssets().open("client-cert.pem").toString());
```

Comment: check this, on how to read the files from assets folder https://stackoverflow.com/a/9544781/8035260

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already tried to do it using InputStream and buffer and it was not a solution. I think it has to do more with something that needs to be done to .pem certificates

Comment: do you have problem in reading .pem file? @albert

Comment: I think so, because the SSL connection does not work in my program and after many tests the only possibility is that I am not reading the .pem certificates well. I have read that maybe I have to transform them to another file, for example with extension .jks but I am not sure about this.