# How can I download a CSV file from res/raw folder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, raw

Suppose I have a sample.csv file in my project res/raw folder. Now in an activity, there is a button "Download CSV", when click this button then the CSV file is download to the user's external storage.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.  please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question. Good luck 

Comment: Instead of raw directory use assets directory. [How to read a file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)