# open text from assets

Tags: android, stdio

how can I open txt file uesing Intent if anyone there can help please tell me

```
private void StoryData() {
    Story story1 = null;
    try {
        story1 = new Story( "the king" , getString(getAssets().open("text1.txt")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    storyList.add(story1);
        Story story2 = new Story("the pirence" , "");
        storyList.add(story2);
        Story story3 = new Story("my story", "");
        storyList.add(story3);


    storyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private String getString(InputStream open) {
```

Comment: This question is already asked click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)