How to refer to a file in project directory in Android Studio?
I have a problem. I need to make refrence to file credentials.json in java file in Android Studio that will work when i create APK file. I created new directory assets in project/app/src/main and put file there.
Andorid Studio view
How can I make a refrence to this path? I understand that later its get ResourceAsStream metohod but i can't figure out how to merge this
I tried absolute paths, both \ and / but nothing seems to work. I check it also with Python equivalent to this code and it's works there

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9544737/150978
