# What are the commands to read a .csv file and skip the first row in Python 2.4.3

Tags: python, csv, python-2.4

I learned how to script in python with version 2.7; however, the system I am coding on now only has version 2.4.3.  I am trying to open a file titled "input.csv", read columns 0, 1, 2 and 3, while simultaneously skipping the first row since it contains header information that I do not want.  The code I am attaching works fine with Python 2.7.9, but does not work with 2.4.3. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how this block of code should be written.

```
import csv          # imports the library that enables functionality to read .csv files

MATPRO_Temperature  = []  # List to hold MATPRO experimental temperatures
MATPRO_Density      = []  # List to hold MATPRO experimental densities
MATPRO_Conductivity = []  # List to hold MATPRO experimental thermal conductivities
MATPRO_References   = []  # List to hold MATPRO references for each measurement

File_Name = 'Input.csv'   # - The relative address for the MATPRO database containing
                          #   the thermal conductivity measurements

# This section opens the .csv file at the address 'File_Name' and reads in its data into lists
with open(File_Name) as csvfile:
  next(csvfile)  # This forces the reader to skip the header row of hte .csv file
  readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
  for row in readCSV:
    MATPRO_Temperature.append(row[0])
    MATPRO_Density.append(row[1])
    MATPRO_Conductivity.append(row[2])
    MATPRO_References.append(row[3])
```

Comment: Python 2.4 is over 10 years old and has been EOL for years. Is there any reason why you're stuck on 2.4? Can't you upgrade to 2.7?

Comment: Bjorn, unfortunately in the business I work in, things seldom ever make sense.  Python is freeware, so upgrading should be simple, but our IT group refuses to update the Python code on our Linux system and I am not allowed to do it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/csv-contents.html, you need to `read` the csv file before calling `next` on it. Also, the `with` keyword isn't in Python till version 2.5.

```
 csvfile = open(File_Name, 'r') # 'r' -> read only
 try:
      readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
      next(readCSV) # move it here, and call next on the reader object
      for row in readCSV:
            ...
 finally:
       csvfile.close()
```

---

**Explanation:** The reason for `try` and `finally` is explained here [How to safely open/close files in python 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770348/how-to-safely-open-close-files-in-python-2-4), but basically, you want to make sure you close the file properly (which is what the `with` keyword does) even if there is an error.

Comment: Unfortunately Python 2.4.3 does not like the with open() command

Comment: There is no `next()` function in Python 2.4; use `reader.next()` instead. Also, use `rb` mode for csv file in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the enumerate() function

```
  f = open("Input.csv")
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i==0:
        continue

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  reader.next()

```
reader = csv.DictReader(reading_file,fieldnames=firstline,delimiter=',')

reader.next()
```